# Extracting sub data from large one

Tags: list-manipulation, data

```
LargData = 
   Table[{i, 2 i, 3 i}, {i, 10000000}]; // AbsoluteTiming

 {0.450277, Null}
```

I want to extract specific columns from the data above but it takes time which is even larger than creating the `LargData`. Here are my tries:

```
 {#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ LargData; // AbsoluteTiming

{2.20556, Null}
```

second:

```
{#1, #2} & @@@ LargData; // AbsoluteTiming

{7.46066, Null}
```

which takes even longer, is there a faster way to extract such data from big files?

**Update-1**

As @Daniel Huber pointed out `LargData[[All, 1 ;; 2]]` can be efficient but I want to perform some operations on the extracted data such as taking the `Sin` of the second element `{#[[1]], Sin[#[[2]]]} & /@ LargData`, this takes 12 sec

Comment: `dat1 = LargData[[All, 1 ;; 2]]; // AbsoluteTiming` This takes 0.1 sec.

Comment: @DanielHuberm I am aware of that but I want to do some operation on the extracted element such as taking sin like `{#1, Sin[#2]} & @@@ LargData`, in this case, your approach is not useful.

Comment: `{#, Sin[#2]} & @@ (LargData\[Transpose][[;; 2]]) // Transpose; // AbsoluteTiming`

Answer (score 4):

```
(data = Table[{i, 2 i, 3 i}, {i, 10000000}];) // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

0.345369

```
(a = {#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ data;) // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

0.777515

```
(b = data[[All, 1 ;; 2]];) // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

0.086123

```
a == b
```

(* True *)

```
$Version
```

"13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)"